# align three children left, right and center within LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Maybe a duplicate, but I haven't found a solution yet. So, I have a vertical LinearLayout with a header which is a horizontal layout and a main content section (FrameLayout). Within the header I got three children of which one should be left align, the other one right aligned and the third on should fill the space in between.

[image: android layout]

I think I have to use a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout, but if I do so, it fill's the parent completely and nothing else is visible.

Any suggestion? Basically the two button inside the red rectangle should be aligned to the right.

Here's the XML.

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sort_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/sort_by"
                android:textColor="@color/white80"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/view_group"
                style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="0dp" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_view_grid"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="onShowGrid"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_grid" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_view_list"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="onShowGrid"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_list" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/sort_group"
                style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="0dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sort_popular"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                    android:text="@string/sort_popular"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/sort_button_selector"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sort_new"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                    android:text="@string/sort_newest"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/sort_button_selector"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sort_hard"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                    android:text="@string/sort_hardest"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/sort_button_selector"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sort_easy"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                    android:text="@string/sort_easiest"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/sort_button_selector"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/preview_fragment"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why not set the weight of the one in the middle to 1 and the rest to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to achieve this. I had to use the following values inside a **RelativeLayout** instead of a LinearLayout correctly:

- android:layout_gravity="center"
- android:layout_centerVertical="true"
- android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view_group"
- android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_sort"

Here's the XML:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sort_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_sort"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:text="@string/sort_by"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white80"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/view_group"
                style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:padding="0dp" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_view_grid"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="onShowGrid"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_grid" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btn_view_list"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="onShowList"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_list" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/sort_group"
                style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view_group"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/label_sort"
                android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="0dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sort_popular"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                    android:text="@string/sort_popular"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/sort_button_selector"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sort_new"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                    android:text="@string/sort_newest"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/sort_button_selector"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sort_hard"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                    android:text="@string/sort_hardest"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/sort_button_selector"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_sort_easy"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                    android:text="@string/sort_easiest"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/sort_button_selector"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </RadioGroup>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/preview_fragment"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

something similar may help

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sort_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="sort_by"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/sort_group"
            style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="0dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sort_popular"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                android:text="sort_popular"
                android:textColor="#FFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sort_new"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                android:textColor="#FFFF"
                android:text="sort_newest"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sort_hard"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                android:textColor="#FFFF"
                android:text="sort_hardest"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sort_easy"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:onClick="onSortChanged"
                android:textColor="#FFFF"
                android:text="sort_easiest"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RadioGroup>


<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/sort_layout2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_view_grid"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:onClick="onShowGrid"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_grid" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_view_list"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:onClick="onShowGrid"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_view_as_list" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_fragment"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```